# Как убрать или скрыть breadcrumbs только на домашней странице?

Tags: wordpress, breadcrumbs, yoast

Всем привет,
Я использую yoast seo и установил breadcrumb вставил положил следующий код в header.php.

```
   <? php if (function_exists ('yoast_breadcrumb')) {
   yoast_breadcrumb ('<p id ='breadcrumbs'>', «</ p>');
   }?>
```

Всё заработало, но единственная проблема, которую я имею, состоит в том, что я не хочу, чтобы крошки показывались на моей домашней странице 
   [как выглядеть на сайте](http://joxi.ru/D2PxXK9Hp3Y5X2)

И еще одна вещь, на самом деле я новичок в этой области тем
поэтому я спрошу если  отключитьbreadcrumbs  из home page будет ли какой-либо SEO-эффект.

Comment: По поводу сео вопроса, это лучше задать отдельный вопрос с соответствующими метками.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функция [is_front_page](https://wp-kama.ru/function/is_front_page) или в некоторых случаях [is_home](https://wp-kama.ru/function/is_home).

```
<?php 
   if( !is_front_page() ) {
    if (function_exists ('yoast_breadcrumb')) {
       yoast_breadcrumb ('<p id="breadcrumbs">', '</p>');
     }
    }
?>
```

Или

```
<?php 
   if (function_exists ('yoast_breadcrumb') AND !is_front_page()) {
     yoast_breadcrumb ('<p id="breadcrumbs">', '</p>');
   }
?>
```

Comment: Спасибо Саша работает!

Comment: @olegin да не за что) Ставим плюс и галочку)

Comment: там кавычки нужно поменять, перед закрывающим тэгом p...

Comment: А ещё такой вопрос чтобы этот код вставить в function.php , что нужно поменять в нём?

Comment: @olegin это уже отдельный вопрос, и ответ будет зависеть от вашей темы